# Importing & manipulating images with PILLOW

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use the python image library to import an image. I keep getting an error that says the file or directory doesn't exist when I run this code:

```
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open("Users/tylercordeiro/hello/sunrisesunsettime.jpeg")
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Is there a specific way that I need to put in the name of my file/directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try with an absolute path. I have added a `/` or `slash` at the beginning of the file name.

```
from PIL import Image 
im = Image.open("/Users/tylercordeiro/hello/sunrisesunsettime.jpeg")
im
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks!!